# Phalcon: how to run example unit test?

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, phalcon

I tried to run an example from here:
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/unit-testing.html

I created composer file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phalcon/incubator": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

After composer installation I've tried to run phpunit and got an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Codeception\TestCase\Test' not found in /www/tests/vendor/phalcon/incubator/codeception/unit/Phalcon/Validation/Validator/Db/UniquenessTest.php on line 9
```

I added new dependency:

```
composer require "codeception/codeception:*"
```

It added many dependencies.

After that I got another error:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(tests/data/app/data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in www/tests/vendor/codeception/codeception/tests/unit/Codeception/Module/FacebookTest.php on line 3
```

I changed

```
require_once(tests/data/app/data.php)
```

to

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../../tests/data/app/data.php')
```

in follow follow files:

```
www/tests/vendor/codeception/codeception/tests/unit/Codeception/Module/WebDriverTest.php
www/tests/vendor/codeception/codeception/tests/unit/Codeception/Module/WFacebookTest.php
www/tests/vendor/codeception/codeception/tests/unit/Codeception/Module/PhpBrowserTest.php
```

Ok. Phpunit running...I've got next error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WebDriverTestCase' not found in `www/tests/vendor/facebook/webdriver/tests/functional/BaseTest.php on line 16`
```

Ok.. I tried to include:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/WebDriverTestCase.php';
```

to

```
www/tests/vendor/facebook/webdriver/tests/functional/BaseTest.php
```

**Now I have following error which I cannot fix:**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message 'Class "PHPUnit_Extensions_RepeatedTest" does not extend PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.' in www/tests/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:195
Stack trace:
#0 /www/tests/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(324): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->__construct(Object(ReflectionClass))
#1 /www/tests/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(409): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestSuite(Object(ReflectionClass))
#2 /www/tests/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(435): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFile('/Users/anthony/...')
#3 phar:///usr/local/zend/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Util/Configuration.php(911): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFiles(Array)
#4 phar:///usr/local/zend/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Util/Configuration.php(825): PHPUnit_Util_Configura in /www/tests/UnitTestCase.php on line 61
```

I thought composer should make your life easer by it seems doesn't. Is it ok I have to change some code in vendor libraries?!... where I'm doing wrong? I just need to use phpunit in phalcon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time I finished reading the question I was expecting to see "Ok… I took a gun and shoot twice in a stomach…" I am a little uncertain if you are trying to run tests from incubator or Phalcon, or your own. I am assuming your own.

First of all incubator is an interesting repository, but it's probably the last thing you need to use in your project. It's meant to make your life easier, but most stuff are experimental there and act more as an inspiration rather than a solution (imho). It's supported by less involved people and the reason why it doesn't work might also be the difference in PHPUnit versions (incubator uses 3.7, the rest of the contemporary world uses 4.2, which have some incompatibilities).

Phalcon works perfectly fine with PHPUnit out of the box. To run basic tests all you need is to install and configure PHPUnit as per [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.composer). The simplest phpunit.xml can look like this:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="../../public/bootstrap.php">
    <testsuite name="Default">
        <directory>../../src/php</directory>
    </testsuite>
</phpunit>
```

I suggest get rid of incubator (at least for your tests until you successfully configure PHPUnit) and follow the standard documentation.

Comment: I follow the documentation and your comment. Now I am getting "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'UnitTestCase' not found in ...". Do you have any idea why this is coming?

Why phalcon guys cant give a working set of code.

Comment: Phalcon guys must be super busy, don't be mad at them. This was two years ago, a lot might have changed and I didn't keep track of it, can't say for certain what's wrong. At the first sight this is the problem with autoloader – it can't `UnitTestCase` class. Check all the paths in composer.json and phpunit configuration.